# Bash script: after installation script following command isn't executed

Tags: bash, shell, fish

I just want to write a small script to automate my fish shell installation. Part of that installation includes calling the official omf `oh-my-fish` installer script (curl ...).

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo apt update \
&& sudo apt install fish -y \
&& sudo chsh -s /usr/bin/fish \
&& curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oh-my-fish/oh-my-fish/master/bin/install | fish \
&& fish -c "omf install bira" \
&& echo -e "\nDone.\n"
```

Unfortunately, after the curl install command none of the following commands in my script are executed, it fails to continue. Does someone have an answer for this?

Update: Sorry for the inaccurate description of my problem. I've edited my question and I hope now everybody understands it better. If my description is still not good enough, please just tell me and I will edit it again.

Comment: maybe the install script hasn't terminated - is it waiting for input?

Comment: In some cases yes, but not of you do a blank install.

Comment: I suspect something in the script is reading from standard input, and hence stealing what you meant to be read as commands. But I'm not familiar enough with fish syntax to say how to solve this.

Comment: I would run it as `... | fish  --init-command='set fish_trace on'` and see where it hangs.

Comment: @GordonDavisson It is a bash script to install fish with omf.

Comment: @user1934428 Thanks for the hint but I don't know  if the last commands of the script are the root of the evil? The two last line of the output are "Installation successful!" and
"--> set -q NONINTERACTIVE".

Comment: Since your problem seems to be related to _fish_ and not to bash, I would properly tag it as _fish_ to attract people who know fish (I don't). Also, I don't understand why you insist in blindly doing a `curl .... | fish`, instead first downloading the installation file, then opening a fish shell and, after manually having a look at the install script, run it within the fish shell.

Comment: Thanks for the tip the tag is now changed. There are two resons for my approach. Firstly, I thought I could write a small noninteractive installation script in no time. And secondly I am not that much of an experienced script writer. Therefore your tip to write the script differently did not come to me. I was just wondering what is so wrong with just executing the curl command?

Comment: _"It is a bash script to install fish with omf."_ Why do you pipe it to `fish` instead of `bash`?

Comment: @Fravadona That confused me as well, and it took several times reading the question to understand.  As far as I can tell, the OP didn't include the actual bash script in the question.  They are saying that they are calling that particular oh-my-fish installation line inside a bash script, which then fails to continue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to do something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oh-my-fish/oh-my-fish/master/bin/install | fish 
echo "Why doesn't this run?"
echo "Do something else!"
```

But the last two lines don't execute, right?

###### Short answer

Several solutions that I can think of:

- Run the oh-my-fish installer with the `--noninteractive` flag using process substitution:

  ```
  fish <(curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oh-my-fish/oh-my-fish/master/bin/install) --noninteractive
  ```
- Exit the fish shell that oh-my-fish creates by either `exit` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> -- The remainder of your bash script should execute at that point.

###### More Detail

The problem is that the oh-my-fish installation script includes this "clean-up" section at the end:

```
# We made it!
say "Installation successful!"

# Open a brand new shell if we are in interactive mode.
set -q NONINTERACTIVE
  or exec fish < /dev/tty
```

That final line does two things:

- `exec` replaces the fish shell that the installer is running in with a new `fish` shell so that oh-my-fish is ready to use in that shell instance
- The `< /dev/tty` forces that new shell to start reading input from the terminal.  Without this, the script would exit, returning to your calling script.  The developer of the installer doesn't want this to happen - They want the new fish instance to be "ready to go" with oh-my-fish after the installer runs.

Regardless, that combination will prevent any "containing" script from continuing to execute until the new fish instance is terminated.

You can see this in a bit of an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

`test_exec.fish`:

```
#!/usr/bin/fish
exec fish < /dev/tty
echo "This never runs"
```

`wrapper.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cat test_exec.fish | fish
echo "Why doesn't this run?"
```

Executing `wrapper.sh` results in no output, since the `test_exec.fish` created a new `fish` instance that reads from the terminal.

However, if you run `ps` after running `./wrapper.sh`, you can see that there's more going on behind the scenes:

```
$ ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 1494 pts/1    00:00:00 fish
 1751 pts/1    00:00:00 bash
 1753 pts/1    00:00:00 fish
 1904 pts/1    00:00:00 ps
```

The first `fish` (pid 1494, for reference here) is where you started; the `bash` is still running the `wrapper.sh` script; and the last `fish` is the one reading that we forced to read from `/dev/tty` and is now reading and executing `ps`.

As mentioned above, if you exit the last `fish` with either `exit` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, `bash ./wrapper.sh` will continue running, output:

```
Why doesn't this run?
```

It will then automatically exit the script/`bash` and return to the original `fish` (pid 1494):

```
$ ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 1494 pts/1    00:00:00 fish
 1958 pts/1    00:00:00 ps
```

Note that, at least on my system, the `tty` redirection causes some issues, such as broken <kbd>Backspace</kbd> that need to be corrected with a terminal `reset` command.

---

Alternatively, we can prevent the `exec fish < /dev/tty` from running at all by calling the installer with the `--noninteractive` flag.

To pass a flag to the script that you are downloading, we use process substitution.  This replaces:

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oh-my-fish/oh-my-fish/master/bin/install | fish
```

with

```
fish <(curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oh-my-fish/oh-my-fish/master/bin/install) --noninteractive
```

Note that if you were calling this from a `fish` script, instead of a `bash` script, the syntax would be:

```
fish (curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/oh-my-fish/oh-my-fish/master/bin/install | psub) --noninteractive
```

Comment: Thank you for your very good explanation! Based on this I could finish my installation script.