# Bash script not executing after installation of ng project

Tags: linux, bash, shell, curl

I have an issue which I'm struggling with.

I'm writing a `.sh` script which is to be executed in our CI pipeline to test if some installation scripts are still working.

The command I'm struggling with in particular is:

`bash <(curl -s https://myhost/path/to/installation/angular.sh)`

From other posts on Stackoverflow, I've learned that there are different ways to cURL and execute the `.sh` script. I've tried them all.

In my case it was always either...

1. The script stops after the `ng new` command is done
2. Or the installation is successful but the following commands in my script are not executed.

For context here is the script:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e # exit on errors
BASE_DIR="$( cd "$(dirname "$0")" ; pwd -P )"

source $BASE_DIR/bashHelpers.sh
ANGULAR_EXAMPLE_FOLDER="angularTest"

#Run Angular Tests
bash -c "$(curl -s https://myhost/path/to/installation/angular.sh)"
#I've also tried:
#curl -s https://myhost/path/to/installation/angular.sh | bash -s -- $ANGULAR_EXAMPLE_FOLDER
# OR
#curl -s https://myhost/path/to/installation/angular.sh | bash -s -- $ANGULAR_EXAMPLE_FOLDER > yes  

(   
    BASE_DIR="$( cd "$(dirname "$0")" ; pwd -P )"
    source $BASE_DIR/bashHelpers.sh
    cypress run --env configFile=setuptest --browser chrome -c video=false &&
    killWebserver 4200
    rm -rf $ANGULAR_EXAMPLE_FOLDER 
)
```

The process in my script is pretty simple:

1. cURL and execute an installation script
2. run the installed project
3. run a cypress test
4. if cypress is successful, stop the server
5. delete project
6. proceed with next script

Would really appreciate some help on that one, as this [related topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70617551/bash-script-after-installation-script-following-command-isnt-executed) wasn't of any help to me sadly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to resolve the issue and make the script more adaptable to parameteres:

```
#Run acutal test
(set -e && waitForWebServer $PORT $TESTURL) & (
curl -s $URL > ./setup.sh &&
printf '\n' | source ./setup.sh test)
```

The `printnf '\n' | source ./setup.sh test` line resolves the issue of the bash being locked by the `ng cli` during the installation.
And the aspect of the sub bashs via which the two parts `waitForWebServer` and `run the setup script` are executed enables to run those commands in parallel. Thus, saving some runtime without unnecessary `sleep` commands.